# Curl No URL set! 3 Error

Tags: php, curl, joomla

I am using curl to fetch result from Punchtab when I execute this code I am getting curl exception 3 No URL set! can any one help me with it.

```
$tocken2 =  "https://api.punchtab.com/v1/user?access_token=".$rest->authResponse->accessToken;

  $ch1 = curl_init();
  $ca = 'c:/path/to/ca-bundle.crt';
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$tocken2);

    curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://locatefirms.in");        
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch1);
    $errorMsg = curl_error($ch1);
    $errorNumber = curl_errno($ch1);
    echo $errorMsg;
    echo $errorNumber;
    echo $server_output;exit;
```

Comment: @Elby - comments to comments please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your curl handle is `$ch1`, but you're setting the URL option to `$ch`.

```
$ch1 = curl_init(); // initializing $ch1 here
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$tocken2); // setting option to $ch
```

Quite obviously, to fix this, you need to change the statement to

```
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL,$tocken2);
```